# javascript - jquery $.get function

Tags: javascript, jquery

> I need to use $.get to parse returned page content, the problem that the page URL contains request parameters (query string) as shown below, so the function not work. 
>   so any one have any suggestions

```
 $.get('test123.aspx?param1=123', function (data) {
            console.log("aaa");
            var my_div = $('#my_div', $(data));}
```

Comment: The querystring doesn't have anything to do with jQuery being able to parse the page. If the querystring makes it not work, the problem is within the aspx page.

Comment: I checked again the problem is that i call the page on an external URL for example "servername:5551/sitename/page.aspx?id=123abc"; so do you sir have any idea how to get the page using $.get in this case – user2262205

Comment: Yes, either use CORS, or JSONP.

Answer (score 1):

You should not build the URL yourself but use the builtin capabilities of [$.get](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) :

```
$.get(
    'test123.aspx',
    {param1:"123"}, // jQuery will do the encoding
    function (data) {
        console.log("aaa");
        var my_div = $('#my_div', $(data));}
```

Comment: I checked again the problem is that i call the page on an external URL
for example "http://servername:5551/sitename/page.aspx?id=123abc" so do you sir have any idea how to get the page using $.get in this case